# Validate if ImageButton is filled in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have 3 image buttons where user should select one.

How I can validate if the 3 images buttons are filled?

I have 3 imagebuttons:

```
ImageButton satisfeito = (ImageButton) findViewById(button2);
ImageButton indiferente = (ImageButton) findViewById(button3);
ImageButton nadasatisfeito = (ImageButton) findViewById(button4);
```

If I click on one of them, then it shows a message:

```
satisfeito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Satisfeito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
    
indiferente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Indiferente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
    
nadasatisfeito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nada Satisfeito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

However, I don't know how to see if this 3 imagebuttons are selected. How I can do this?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if view.isSelected() {
                        view.setSelected(false);
                    }
}
```

Kind regards,

Ricardo Diz

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by filled? what do you mean by "if these 3 image buttons are selected"?

Comment: From your question it seems like you want to use buttons as check boxes, if so then here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68247219/14084688

Answer (score 0):

here! using flag concepts

```
int seleted =0;

satisfeito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            seleted=1;
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Satisfeito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
    
indiferente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            seleted=2;
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Indiferente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
    
nadasatisfeito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            seleted=3;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nada Satisfeito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //if view.isSelected() {
                        //view.setSelected(false);

                      if(selected == 0){
                     if(selected==1){
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Satisfeito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if(selected ==2){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Indiferente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else if(selected == 3){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Nada Satisfeito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
                    
                   }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please select one button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                    }
}
```